# Azure auto-run a script on a VM

Tags: azure, automation, cloud

I want to automate these 3 steps:

1. Create a VM
2. Run a bash script: To configure this newly created VM and run a script. I intend to setup the VM, download code from git and execute the process as required.
3. Auto delete the VM on successful completion

Whether its a successful completion or unexpected exit will be monitored by a monitoring process which can be run as a daemon before the main process starts. In which case, we can trigger restart as a failsafe mechanism.

I'm using Azure cloud to run my process.

### My questions:

1. Is what I'm thinking a decent way to tackle this use case?
2. Which tools in Azure cloud can help me with this?

Comment: Are you sure you need a VM to do this?  Would a container, Azure Function or Web App do what you need?  A function would be the most cost-effective.

Comment: Why not...I'm exploring the possibilities here. This is why I put my 1st question, which is a bit subjective. But some hints on tools to use would be just great. @KenWMSFT
I'm going to look into `azure functions` or `azure web app` now.

Comment: Just for the record, I'm very new to Azure cloud so I'm not very aware of its components. Also, I would like to mention here that my process is CPU intensive and takes 8 to 24 hours to complete - depending on input volume.

Comment: 8-24 hours of compute would rule out most PaaS (Functions, Web App, etc) services so IaaS (VM) is probably the right choice.  You might be able to do this with a container but again, really depends on what the code is actually doing.  I will try to write-up an IaaS answer later today if nobody beats me to it.

Comment: @KenWMSFT that would be much helpful...

Answer (score 0):

### Create a VM

Several Options to choose from.

- **Option 1**: [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/quick-create-cli).
- **Option 2**: [Arm Template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/quickstarts/microsoft.compute/vm-simple-linux).
- **Option 3**: [Terraform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/terraform/create-linux-virtual-machine-with-infrastructure).
- **More not listed**: BICEP, PowerShell, Python, REST...

### Run Bash Script

- **Option 1**: [Azure Custom Script Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-linux) Version 2 with Linux virtual machines. May not work bc there is a 90 min window for the script to run.
- **Option 2**: [Cloud Init](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/using-cloud-init). Requires a specific image to work.
- **Option 3**: Cron Job. We don't have any Azure specific documentation.

### Deprovision

As for deprovisioning, you can run the Azure CLI inside the VM after your task is done to delete the VM.  The easiest way to do this is with a [system-assigned managed identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/enable-managed-identity-for-automation).

By default, when you delete a VM it only deletes the VM resource, not the networking and disk resources. You can change this default behavior when you create a VM, or update an existing VM, to [delete specific resources along with the VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/delete?tabs=cli2).

The cleanest method is to create the VM and all components associated with that VM in a single Resource Group (RG).  That way when your script is complete you can just delete the RG and be done.

`az group delete --name ExampleResourceGroup`